# Put annotation and Resteasy best practice

Tags: java, http, rest, resteasy, put

What would be the best practice for the working with the @PUT in the rest world. I have a simple method

```
@PUT
@Path("/")
public boolean putShotComponentNote(String note) {
    System.out.println(note);
    return true;
}
```

And when I try to access this method using the plugin for the Chrome like Simple REST Client or REST Console where I specify the url and in the data segment I put key value pair

```
note=This is some note
```

In my method I get both key and value. Ideally I would like only to get the value based on the name of the variable like I can see in some examples from the http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html-single/RESTEasy_Reference_Guide/index.html

```
@PUT
@Path("array")
@Consumes("application/xml")
public void putCustomers(Customer[] customers)
{
  Assert.assertEquals("bill", customers[0].getName());
  Assert.assertEquals("monica", customers[1].getName());
}
```

So can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks all

Is it possible that this is the difficult?

This is the request that is sent

```
 Request Url:       
 http://localhost:8080/rest/
 Request Method: PUT
 Status Code: 415
 Params: {
     "note": "asd"
 }
```

So how do I access the notes param? The @PathParam wont work, nor will @QueryParam and just plain String not (as written above) gets me note=asd and I would like to avoid that.

So is this possible

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your parameters are being sent in. Since your data isn't being detected by @QueryParam, your data could be inside of a form.

Give @FormParam a try:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_FormParam

I recently ran into this while sending a PUT request via JQuery's ajax function. Here's how you can call the REST service:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"PUT",
    url:"/rest/",
    data:{  "var1": "val1",
            "var2" : "val2"}
});
```

If you're just looking to get string values of the parameters, RESTEasy has an easy way of getting them via the java.util.list object. I used URL encoding as an example, but this can be applied to others as well:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void Method1(@FormParam("var1") List<String> list1,
                    @FormParam("var2") List<String> list2){
    String v1 = list1.get(0);
    String v2 = list1.get(0);

    System.out.println(v1);
    System.out.println(v2);
}
```

Output:

```
val1
val2
```